# Passing parameters to macro with a loop

Tags: loops, parameters, macros, abap

There is a task to fill deep structure with macro, where names of structure components are similar and can be constructed by simple loop with index.
For example, the structure is root-level1-level2-level3-level4

I wanna fill it with following nested macros

```
DEFINE iterate_menges.
 do &4 times.
  fill &1 &2 sy-index level4.
 enddo.
END-OF-DEFINITION.

DEFINE fill.
 cs_root-sheet&1-&2-level&3-&4 = 'some_value'.
END-OF-DEFINITION.
```

But this concept doesn't work and `sy-index` is treated like a text. The error

> component cs_root-sheet1-level2-*levelsy-index-level4* is not found

is shown, however numeric literal works wonderfully.

What syntax should be used here?

**ADDITION:** here is an example snippet I found on SCN and it works perfectly. Why is so?

```
DEFINE ADD_MAPPING.
 p_c = &1.
 CONDENSE p_c.
 CONCATENATE 'p_old' p_c INTO p_c.
 ASSIGN (p_c) TO <fs>.
 WRITE <fs>.
END-OF-DEFINITION.

DO 14 TIMES.
 ADD_MAPPING sy-index.
ENDDO.
```

P.S. Yes, I know macros are undebuggable, unsafe and totally shouldn't be used, but I am interested in this particular problem and not best-practice advice.

Comment: PS: I don't see you using that 5th parameter (level4) in the `fill` macro...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dynamic programming, change your `fill` macro to:

```
  DATA l_field TYPE string.
  FIELD-SYMBOLS <l_value> TYPE any.
  DEFINE fill.
    l_field = &3.
    CONDENSE l_field.
    CONCATENATE 'cs_root-sheet&1-&2-level' l_field '-&4' INTO l_field.
    ASSIGN (l_field) TO <l_value>.
    IF sy-subrc = 0.
      <l_value> = 'some_value'.
    ELSE.
      " TODO: error handling?
    ENDIF.
  END-OF-DEFINITION.
```

This will work, although you might want to check `sy-subrc` after the `ASSIGN` because that parameter is invariant (only known at runtime) and thus will not pick up errors at compile-time like the other parameter would.

You can also add compile-time validation for the upper-bound of your `DO` loop since you thus know the maximum value of `sy-index`. To do this, you can add a non-executing reference in the `iterate_menges` macro:

```
  DEFINE iterate_menges.
    IF 1 = 0. " compile-time boundary validation test
      cs_root-sheet&1-&2-level&4-level4 = ''.
    ENDIF.
    DO &4 TIMES.
     fill &1 &2 sy-index level4.
    ENDDO.
  END-OF-DEFINITION.
```

A second method is to add a case statement. This can only be used if you know there will always be a certain amount of fields in that part (surely there should always be at least one...). So if you know the bottom bound of your `DO` loop, then you can code the following as a optimization:

```
  CASE &3.
    WHEN 1. " set 1
    WHEN 2. " set 2
    WHEN 3. " set 3
    " ...

    WHEN OTHERS.
      " dynamic set
  ENDCASE.
```

Since the dynamic set is slower, optimizing tight loops is always a good idea.

Comment: Good, it works! I corrected your snippet a bit, as *sy-index* is a 3rd parameter of *fill* macro, not the 1st. Also, `CONDENSE` should be applied to *l_field* as `ASSIGN` falls into short dump if not to trimming leading extra space before loop counter.

Comment: Thanks, missed that! I had to do some blind typing as I did not have the source structure types you referenced. Also worked around the parameter problem I detected on the original post.

Answer (score 1):

The system is doing exactly what is stated in the [documentation](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/abenmacro_include.htm). Unfortunately, in this case, the English translation is lacking some details as opposed to the German original text which is more to the point, IMHO. Usage of a macro is not a **call** of some sort, it's a **textual replacement** that happens before compilation. The parameters are replaced, not evaluated - they **can not** be evaluated because in most cases, the value is not known at compile time, only at runtime. To do what you want to do, you will have to use dynamic access techniques like `ASSIGN COMPONENT ... OF ...`

Comment: Maybe some inline conversion can be conducted or something else? The task which requires one-line macro, should be rewritten by the dozens of lines if we use dynamic approach:)

Comment: BTW, how can you explain the macro from my addition to question?

Comment: Just a guess but maybe this code snippet from SDN works because there there are no nested macros there?

Comment: Moreover the macro from SCN works because at the preprocessing time, there is a simple change `p_c = &1` will evaluate to `p_c = sy-index` which is syntactically correct. As vwegert mentioned: at the runtime there are no macros anymore, they are replaced while preprocessing and then compiled, so there is no way you could dynamically construct such an access to the field of a structure.

Comment: Again. Macros are evaluated and replaced during compilation, when the value of sy-index that you want to place in the source code as part of a component name can not be known. The macro you picked up from SCN does just what I suggested by using ASSIGN, although it gets by without COMPONENT OF

Comment: @Jagger, but can we make similar change (like `p_c = &1`) at the preprocessing time in our case? I tried to assign parameter to text variable but was unsuccessful.

Comment: @Suncatcher I am not sure what you mean. Could you post your code in the comment?

Comment: @Jagger, I meant *can one adapt my macro alike those one from SCN in some way*? I didn't clearly get idea of [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770299/passing-parameters-to-macro-with-a-loop/41771083?noredirect=1#comment70748999_41771083) explaining the difference how parameters are used in my vs SCN macro.

Comment: @Suncatcher I updated my answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score -2):

What you are trying to do is impossible, because the macros are only known at compilation time. They are no part of means of modularization in ABAP.

One could even write his own version of [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck). Look at the following example.

```
REPORT zzz.

TYPES: BEGIN OF t1,
         sheet1 TYPE c,
         sheet2 TYPE c,
       END OF t1.

DATA:
  cs_root TYPE t1.

DEFINE test.
  cs_root-sheet&1 = 'costam'.
END-OF-DEFINITION.

DEFINE brainfuck.
  &4=>&1&3 &2.
END-OF-DEFINITION.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  brainfuck IF_SYSTEM_UUID_STATIC~CREATE_UUID_X16 ) ( CL_SYSTEM_UUID.
  test sy-index.
```

Answering your comment under the other answer. The solution could look like this.

```
REPORT zzz.

TYPES: BEGIN OF t4,
    level4 TYPE c,
  END OF t4.

TYPES: BEGIN OF t3,
    level1 TYPE t4,
    level2 TYPE t4,
  END OF t3.

TYPES: BEGIN OF t2,
    level1 TYPE t3,
    level2 TYPE t3,
  END OF t2.

TYPES: BEGIN OF t1,
    sheet1 TYPE t2,
    sheet2 TYPE t2,
  END OF t1.

CLASS lcl_test DEFINITION FINAL.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      test
        IMPORTING
          i_1 TYPE i
          i_2 TYPE i
          i_3 TYPE i
        CHANGING
          cs_root TYPE t1.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_test IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD test.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT |sheet{ i_1 }| OF STRUCTURE cs_root TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_sheet>).
    IF sy-subrc = 0.
      ASSIGN COMPONENT |level{ i_2 }| OF STRUCTURE <fs_sheet> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_level1>).
      IF sy-subrc = 0.
        ASSIGN COMPONENT |level{ i_3 }| OF STRUCTURE <fs_level1> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_level2>).
        IF sy-subrc = 0.
          ASSIGN COMPONENT 'level4' OF STRUCTURE <fs_level2> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_level3>).
          IF sy-subrc = 0.
            <fs_level3> = 'some_value'.
          ENDIF.
        ENDIF.
      ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

DEFINE test.
  lcl_test=>test(
    EXPORTING
      i_1 = &1
      i_2 = &2
      i_3 = &3
    CHANGING
      cs_root = &4
  ).
END-OF-DEFINITION.

DATA: gs_root TYPE t1.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  DO 14 TIMES.
    test 1 2 sy-index gs_root.
  ENDDO.
```